# 'ConnectedServicesPackages' - Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015

When opening a project, this dialog window comes up:

[image: warning]

Here is the last entry of `ActivityLog.xml`:

> 443
>       2015/12/05 12:15:28.599
>       Error
>       VisualStudio
>       CreateInstance failed for package [ConnectedServicesPackage][Could not load file or assembly
>   'file:///C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\ep43w4ri.131\Microsoft.VisualStudio.ConnectedServices.Package2.dll'
>   or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file
>   specified.]:{   at
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String
>   codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint,
>   StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean
>   throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean
>   suppressSecurityChecks)
>    at
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String
>   codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint,
>   StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean
>   throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean
>   suppressSecurityChecks)
>    at
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName
>   assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly reqAssembly,
>   StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean
>   throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean
>   suppressSecurityChecks)
>    at
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadFrom(String
>   assemblyFile, Evidence securityEvidence, Byte[] hashValue,
>   AssemblyHashAlgorithm hashAlgorithm, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean
>   suppressSecurityChecks, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
>
>   at System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFrom(String assemblyFile, Evidence
>   securityEvidence)
>    at
>   System.Activator.CreateInstanceFromInternal(String assemblyFile,
>   String typeName, Boolean ignoreCase, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder
>   binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[]
>   activationAttributes, Evidence securityInfo)
>    at
>   System.AppDomain.CreateInstanceFrom(String assemblyFile, String
>   typeName)}
>       {8E15F3DA-B303-4AF9-814A-1DC5C2583398}
>
> ---
>
> 80070002
>       Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\ep43w4ri.131\Microsoft.VisualStudio.ConnectedServices.Package2.dll'
>   or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file
>   specified.

Download the [ActivityLog.xml](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=D7CB20B00EA99D79!127776&authkey=!AC0cLizcblITclc&ithint=file%2Cxml).

I realize there are similar question about missing packages, but the solution for each package is different, and I couldn't find any information about my issue.

From the log it seems the dll file is missing, how do I resolve this?

Answer (score 3):

May be you can just search for file Microsoft.VisualStudio.ConnectedServices.Package2.dll in other extensions folders in your C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\ and copy this file (and may be Microsoft.VisualStudio.ConnectedServices.dll) to needed location C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\ep43w4ri.131 (like in question... this location can be different and you must check exactly path in ActivityLog.xml)

This solution works for me.

Answer (score 1):

This is one of the many problems I've had with VS2015 Update 1.

Uninstall the azure extensions Tools->Extensions and Updates..., I can't recall exactly which ones I uninstalled (everything that said "ConnectedServices" or some such), but you can easily re-install later.

Comment: Yes! You are right the problem happened since VS is updated. Will try the solution tonight.

Comment: It didn't work, I've uninstalled everything that has Connected Service in it and reinstall them, although some of them aren't available to be reinstalled.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this problem with Visual Studio Update 2. I wasn't able to shut down Visual Studio anymore. Uninstalling the Microsoft Connected Services extension, resolved the issue. 
**Warning**: It will also uninstall Microsoft Office 365 API tools, Develop Analytics Tools v5.2.0 and Microsoft Azure Storage Connected Services. These extensions cannot be reinstalled later.